# GAE: Setting multiple cookies (or a multi-value cookie) with SimpleCookie

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I'm using Google App Engine. How do I set either multiple cookies or a multi-value cookie with a single response?

Right now I'm using this code from the URL http://localhost:8085/server/showcookie?emailAddress=myemail@gmail.com&secretCode=1

```
C = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
C["emailAddress"] = self.request.get('emailAddress')
C["secretCode"] = self.request.get('secretCode')
C["secretCode"]["path"] = "/"
header_value = C.output(header='')
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", header_value)
```

which doesn't work because the value of header_value is emailAddress="myemail@gmail.com" secretCode=1; Path=/ which is not a well formed header (its missing a comma). How can I create a well formed cookie with both values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two SimpleCookie objects solves it:

```
C1 = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
C1["emailAddress"] = self.request.get('emailAddress')
C2 = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
C2["secretCode"] = self.request.get('secretCode')
C2["secretCode"]["path"] = "/"
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", C1.output(header=''))
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", C2.output(header=''))
```

Answer (score 1):

So, C.output() is attempting to emit 2 complete cookie response header. You've emptied the header name, so the result is 2 values separated by a \r\n.

Do you need to use SimpleCookie? You can [set cookies directly](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#id5) on the WebOb response object.

```
self.response.set_cookie('emailAddress', self.request.get('emailAddress'))
self.response.set_cookie('secretCode', self.request.get('secretCode'), path='/')
```

Comment: App engine doesn't support "set_cookie"

Comment: @yourfriendzak No, webapp doesn't use the webob response object, and hence doesn't have set_cookie. You should consider using webapp2.

Answer (score 1):

Slap in your own set_cookie() routine.

```
import datetime
import Cookie

def set_cookie(self, name, value, expires=None):
    """Set a cookie"""
    if value is None:
        value = 'deleted'
        expires = datetime.timedelta(minutes=-50000)
    jar = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    jar[name] = value
    jar[name]['path'] = u'/'
    if expires:
        if isinstance(expires, datetime.timedelta):
            expires = datetime.datetime.now() + expires
        if isinstance(expires, datetime.datetime):
            expires = expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
        jar[name]['expires'] = expires
    self.response.headers.add_header(*jar.output().split(u': ', 1))
```

You call the function with

```
set_cookie('my_cookie', 'things-you-want-to-add-in-the-cookie') 
set_cookie('1d_cookie', 'only-one-day', datetime.timedelta(minutes=1440))
```